# Asynchronously reloading HTML and JS code makes JS event listeners not react to clicks on reloaded HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, asynchronous

I'm building a site with Game of Life, where only one page is visible to the user. I'm using AJAX to let users submit patterns (handled as series of integers), and the patterns are saved to the server and automatically displayed in a panel. The patterns in the panel are clickable, users can select patterns and place on the grid. Everything works fine until users submit content. When users submit a pattern, the panel and the JS code making the patterns clickable is reloaded. The panel is reloaded as expected, and I see in "inspect element" that also the JS code is reloaded. However the JS is ignored! The JS code contains functions that are called by event listeners (listening for clicks in the panel, which is reloaded upon sumbission) in the dynamically loaded JS code. What confuses me is that it works before the panel is reloaded, but not after. It seems like reloading the panel makes the event listeners lose its association with the panel.

I realize this Question is becoming messy. I will try to summarize:

Page loads: panel is loaded with PHP file_get_contents(), JS event listeners and handlers are loaded asynchronously. Event listeners react to event (click pattern in panel).

User submits content: panel and JS code is reloaded asynchronously (getting panel with single line: file_get_contents in separate php file). Now, event listeners don't react to event (click pattern in panel).

My question is, how do I get around this issue?

for reference, the site is [tunetiles.com](http://www.tunetiles.com). I name the site so you have access to the source, I hope it is not considered advertising.

Comment: You didn't post any relevant code, and your site is either really slow or dead. When you update the DOM (like by setting `innerHTML`) there are two things to know: embedded `<script>` tags won't run, and any event handlers attached to elements that were there before become irrelevant, because that portion of the DOM is completely rebuilt.

Comment: Does this mean that I can't load JS code asynchronously or will it work if I embed the code to my main <script> block? ATM I have an empty <script id="foo"></script>, which the script is loaded to. It works when I asynchronously load code into it on initial page load. The site loads just fine for me btw.

Comment: It means that if you're loading content with embedded JavaScript, you have to strip it out and explicitly `eval()` it. That's a thing that libraries like jQuery will do for you. Better, do what Michal says in the answer: use event delegation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to bind your events using on() method instead of click(). Click bound events will not fire once DOM is rebulid. More info here http://api.jquery.com/on/

As for reloading javascript - Pointy has a good point